# Plugins not working. "Unable to find component class 'ether\seo\fields\SeoField'."

Tags: plugins, redactor, seo, plugin-seo

I deployed a Craft CMS website to a webhosting space today and everything is running fine except for my Plugins (Redactor & SEO). When I open an entry and go to the SEO field, I get this error message: *Unable to find component class 'ether\seo\fields\SeoField'.* I checked and both plugins show up as *enabled* and *installed* in the Control Panel.

When I click on the *enable* button below the error message, a popup shows *"Plugin enabled"*, however the problem persists as mentioned above.

**What I have tried to fix this:**

- uninstall and reinstall the plugins
- deleted the plugins from the vendor folder and ran "composer install"

How do I get my plugins to work correctly? Any help is much appreciated :)

[image: Error Message of the SEO Plugin field (Unable to find component class 'ether\seo\fields\SeoField)]